# How to generate all possible combinations

Tags: ruby, recursion, combinations

I have a string array like this:

```
[
  "productRankingOct12:LessPopularityEPC",
  "productRankingOct12:CtrEpcJob", 
  "productRankingOct12:DeviceSpecificLPE", 
  "guidedSearch:false", 
  "guidedSearch:true", 
  "spotfront4:true", 
  "spotfront4:false",
  "postClick4:ipsa", 
  "postClick4:false",
  "trendingModule:false"
]
```

I have to build URLs based on the given key:value pairs. I want the combinations of the elements:

```
[
  "productRankingOct12:LessPopularityEPC",
  "productRankingOct12:CtrEpcJob", 
  "productRankingOct12:DeviceSpecificLPE",
  "guidedSearch:false", 
  "guidedSearch:true", 
  "productRankingOct12:LessPopularityEPC & guidedSearch:false"
  "productRankingOct12:CtrEpcJob & guidedSearch:false"
  "productRankingOct12:DeviceSpecificLPE & guidedSearch:false"
  "productRankingOct12:LessPopularityEPC & guidedSearch:true"
  "productRankingOct12:CtrEpcJob & guidedSearch:true"
  "productRankingOct12:DeviceSpecificLPE & guidedSearch:true"
  "productRankingOct12:LessPopularityEPC & guidedSearch:false & spotfront4:true"
  "productRankingOct12:CtrEpcJob & guidedSearch:false & "spotfront4:true""
  "productRankingOct12:DeviceSpecificLPE & guidedSearch:false & "spotfront4:true""
  "productRankingOct12:LessPopularityEPC & guidedSearch:true & "spotfront4:true""
]
```

I tried to generate permutations using this:

```
def Automate_AB_tests.permutation(arg_keyVal)
  return [arg_keyVal] if arg_keyVal.size < 2
  ch = arg_keyVal[0] 
  permutation(arg_keyVal[1..-1]).each_with_object([]) do |perm,result|
    (0..perm.size).each {|i| result << perm.dup.insert(i,ch)}
  end
end
```

but it seems it is taking all the elements, and it crashed. I don't want to permute all the elements. I want the desired output as above. Please anyone can help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, I cant' figure out why in your output `"trendingModule:false"` is missing everywhere.

Why the rows `"spotfront4:true"`, `"spotfront4:false"`, `"postClick4:ipsa"`, `"postClick4:ipsa"` etc.. are missing in the output? What's the logic behind the inclusion or the exclusion of each combination?

Shure you want to exclude rows like `"key:true&key:false"` because of the duplicated key.

Second, this program produces every possible combination, but that is not what you want, right? 215 elements, way more than what you listed in the example

```
opts = [
  "productRankingOct12:LessPopularityEPC",
  "productRankingOct12:CtrEpcJob", 
  "productRankingOct12:DeviceSpecificLPE", 
  "guidedSearch:false", 
  "guidedSearch:true", 
  "spotfront4:true", 
  "spotfront4:false",
  "postClick4:ipsa", 
  "postClick4:false",
  "trendingModule:false"
]

normal_opts = Hash.new
opts.each do |e|
  k, v = e.split(":")
  (normal_opts[k] ||= []) << v
end

# normal_ops looks like this
#normal_opts = {
#  "productRankingOct12" => ["LessPopularityEPC", "CtrEpcJob", "DeviceSpecificLPE"],
#  "guidedSearch" => ["false", "true"],
#  "spotfornt4" => ["true", "false"],
#  "postClick4" => ["ipsa", "false"],
#  "trendingModule" => ["false"]
#}

# nobody is ever going to mantain this
result = normal_opts.keys.length.times.map do |i|
  normal_opts.keys.combination(i + 1).map do |keys|
    combs = keys.map { |k|
      normal_opts[k].map { |e|
        "#{k}:#{e}"
      }
    }
    # good luck understanding this!
    combs.first.product(*combs[1..-1]).map{|e| e.join("&")}
  end
end

puts result.flatten
```

If you explain yourself better, I can improve my answer

Comment: Hello I am really sorry. Actually I have not written all the combinations. I just took two strings & wrote all possible combinations. However, I have to consider all possible combinations... If you could help me with this.

Comment: Awesome work you have done for me. Just that I have lots of data so it is taking too long. If you can increase efficiency of this code by anyway, it would be great for me.

Comment: Given the nature of the problem, high computational complexity has to be expected for any solution. Sure the code can be optimized, and maybe you can come up with a solution that is orders of magnitude faster than what it is now, but I feel you are going to hit efficiency problem anyway when you start using the produced data